# SQL Server increment by 1 primary key varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, sql-insert

I have this table "ART":

```
COD - varchar(20) PK
DES - varchar(50)
```

Simple example data are:

```
COD       DES
MM000000  AA
MM000001  BB
MM000010  CC
MM000145  DD
```

How do I increment the column COD by 1 every insert? The final pk format must be: 'MM' + 6 digits

Comment: it is always prefix with `MM` ?

Comment: What happens if you have `MM000000'` to `'MM000010'`, and then the one ending in 5 is deleted? Do 6-10 need to have their values decreased?

Comment: @Squirrel: good question. If all records have to start with 'MM', why waste disk space? And further, if not all values start with 'MM', I would not suggest to use a 'natural' key as a primaray. IMNVHO (In my not very humble opinion) a primary key HAS to be a 'artificial' key (like from a sequence or an identity column)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @a INT = 0;
WHILE @a < 100 
BEGIN
    SELECT 'MM' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(@A as VARCHAR(6)),6)
    SET @a += 1
END


CREATE TABLE #a 
(
    Id  INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Code    AS 'MM' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(Id as VARCHAR(255)),6)
)

INSERT INTO #a DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #a DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #a DEFAULT VALUES

SELECt * FROM #a
```

but identity can be an unevenly growing value

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is better and more safe to define the identity column as a computed column in the table definition

Please refer to SQL tutorial on [Custom Sequence String as SQL Identity Column](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/custom-sequence-string-as-sql-identity-column.aspx)

The solution requires a simple identity column of integer data type increasing by 1 with every insert
Then a second column, actually a computed column created as follows will help you for the solution of your requirement

```
COD as dbo.udf_ZeroPaddingAndConcat('ID-', CAST(Id as nvarchar(10)),6,'0'),
```

Actually the custom function module is just doing the zero padding here as

```
SELECT @Prefix + RIGHT(REPLICATE(@PaddingChar, @Length) + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)), @Length)
```

You will also find the function source code in the same referenced document